# как получить дату каждого файла?

Tags: java

есть путь к папке в папке есть файлы нужно получить дату каждого файла
[image: такой метод написал, но я могу получить дату только папки который находится в пути, мне нужно получить дату каждого файла]

Answer (score 2):

У файла, в зависимости от ОС может быть несколько атрибутов дат (в некоторых ОС их может быть теоретически и бесконечно много), Java поддерживает 3 из них:

1. Время создания
2. Время доступа
3. Время последней модификации

Их можно получить следующим образом:

```
File file; //ваш файл
BasicFileAttributes attr = Files.readAttributes(file.getPath(), BasicFileAttributes.class);
FileTime fileTime = attr.creationTime(); //время создания
fileTime = attr.lastModifiedTime(); //время последней модификации
fileTime = attr.lastAccessTime(); //время последнего доступа
```

Comment: спасибо интересно, не знал что есть такие полезные вещи